# unable to install `wine` in Devuan due to "supposedly identical version of libwine:amd64"

Tags: debian, apt, wine, devuan

I'm in Devuan Chimaera. I had installed it in two machines before the current one.
So I have also installed WINE before on Devuan.

Somehow, strangely, I get this warning:

```
sudo apt install wine wine64 wine32-preloader winbind winetricks --no-install-recommends
blah...blah...

W: Sources disagree on hashes for supposely identical version '5.0.3-3' of 'libwine:amd64'.
```

If I do continue, it gives me a error:

```
You have broken packages
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple repositories providing different variants of the same `libwine` package, version 5.0.3-3. This can happen if, for example, you have both Devuan and Debian repositories configured.

`apt policy libwine:amd64` will list all the repositories known to your system which provide `libwine`, along with the available versions. You should remove any extraneous repositories and try again.